# What anagram of Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore was being referred to by this alleged JKR?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

@JackBNimble managed to pull up an answer to [What were J. K. Rowling's “theories” about book seven?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170657/33591) that, while I'm skeptical, seems at least slightly plausible.

This alleged JKR posted this line at some point:

> ([Name Edited]) Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore now THAT is a HUGE anagram waiting to be solved..... any takers???

Is there actually a hidden anagram in Dumbledore's name? (Note also that [partial anagrams](http://anagram-solver.net/Albus%20Percival%20Wulfric%20Brian%20Dumbledore?partial=true) could be a possibility.)

Comment: [Computer says no](http://anagram-solver.net/Albus%20Percival%20Wulfric%20Brian%20Dumbledore)

Comment: No. She's just mucking with you

Comment: BRO, A  DULL CREEP USED CRIMINAL FLAIR  BUB!

Comment: there's no actual evidence though that the person in question is actually JKR though, right? That alone makes it a specious premise

Comment: A VULNERABLE  BULIMIC WILDCARD POSEUR?

Comment: Calling it slightly plausible is a stretch. It's pretty clear that it wasn't her, as it doesn't fit with the description she gave of her visit.

Comment: American five dollar bill..... Old Albus is clearly an immortal Abraham Lincoln.

Comment: @ibid I think you are reading too much into her statement. To me it doesn't say she only visited one chatroom one time. It says she decided to take a stroll into Harry Potter fan sites, and went into Mugglenet.

Comment: One website gave me this amazing anagram. 'AlbusPercivalWulfricBrianDumbledore' is an anagram of:
Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore

Comment: @JackBNimble - The user in the transcript was a regular for two weeks. Not just someone "taking a stroll".

Answer (score 5):

## There was no anagram.

The most significant anagram of "Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore" is "Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore". The full name of Albus Dumbledore was first revealed in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, long before these supposed theories were posted. No anagram has ever been found for said name, and the name seems quite long for an anagram that anyone could be expected to predict. It would be quite odd for J.K. Rowling to show an anagrammed name in the first of seven books and only ever mention said anagram in a chat with fans who don't know they're speaking to the author.

J.K. Rowling likely wouldn't want to use an anagram as a plot device again after "Tom Marvolo Riddle", lest she is being accused of being lazy and unable to come up with compelling ways to hide a villain's identity. In addition, Tom's name included the fake word "Marvolo", whereas all of Dumbledore's names actually mean something in real life or mythology. For example, Rowling has shared not only the origin of but also why she chose "Dumbledore" as Albus's last name.

> Other names mean something -- Dumbledore, which means "bumblebee" in Old English...seemed to suit the headmaster, because one of his passions is music and I imagined him walking around humming to himself.
> <sub>[Barnes and Noble interview, March 19, 1999](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-barnesandnoble.html)</sub>

There has also never been any hint to Dumbledore's name being an anagram in the books. While "Tom Marvolo Riddle" was never specifically foreshadowed as an anagram either, the name "Riddle" could've clued some readers in as to Tom's name having a deeper meaning. On the other hand, Albus Dumbledore has never been revealed to be an anagram of any kind even in *Deathly Hallows*, the final book.

## Most of her theories were bogus.

While there is evidence that the person we see in the [chat logs](https://alt.fan.harry-potter.narkive.com/XlOR20GI/mugglenet-chat) is not actually Rowling ([Dacium's comment](https://narkive.com/XlOR20GI.3) from 15 years ago sums it up well), it's clear either way that the "theories" she posted were incorrect. She continually stated that the ninth chapter of Goblet of Fire, a chapter primarily relevant to the plot of the book on its own and the events leading up to the return of Voldemort, was significant to the seventh book, even claiming that it had to be rewritten 1213 times. She even went so far as to state that Remus Lupin is the "HALF BLOOD PRINCE", which both relates to the sixth book rather than the seventh (while Rowling said that she posted theories about the seventh book during her chat) and is obviously incorrect to anyone who has read *Half-Blood Prince*. If any of what she posted was ever true, it was scrapped before the last two books were released.